# Autoit with FF.au3 and Mozrepl How would I close all tabs in firefox using _FFClosetab()?

Tags: firefox, scripting, automation, firefox-addon, autoit

I'm using Firefox 3.6 and I think that there may be a compatibility issue with the Autoit script using #include FF.au3 and Mozrepl to close all of Firefox's open tabs with the addon TMP-TabMixPlus 0.3.8.4 installed. Below is the script I'm using and I would like to add something like this _FFTabClose("all", "index") I can't make it work!

```
#Include FF.au3
If _FFConnect() Then
    If _FFOpenURL("file:///C:/firefox.html") Then
        WinSetState("[CLASS:MozillaUIWindowClass]", "", @SW_RESTORE)
    EndIf
Else
    MsgBox(64,"Error","Can't connect to FireFox")
EndIf
```

I want to close all tabs before restoring firefox from system tray. Everything else works fine. I think that it might be my syntax but I can't find anything on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a special function for this.

```
#Include <FF.au3>

_FFStart()
If _FFIsConnected() Then
    _FFTabCloseAll()
    Sleep(3000)
    _FFQuit()
EndIf
```

Works for me just fine with minimized FF 3.6.10.
Also, there is a link to [official docs](http://english.documentation.ff-au3.thorsten-willert.de/ff_functions/_FFTabCloseAll.php) for this function.